# Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be endowed with the Euclidean metric $d_2$. Let S be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

1) Given $x\in S$, is the set $\{y\in S: d_2(x,y) \geq r\}$ closed in S?

2) Given $x\in S$, is the set $\{y\in S: d_2(x,y) \geq r\}$ contained in the closure of $\{y\in S: d_2(x,y) > r\}$ in S?

my intuition for both is yes... 
For 1). I think I need to prove the complement of set in S is open. However, I don't know how to quantify the argument.

Comment: A metric is by definition continuous in the metric space.  The preimage of an open set by a continuous function is open.  This should solve most of the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S'$ be the set in the statement. Let $\{x_k\} \subset S'$ and $x_k \to x'$. Then $r \leq d_2(x_k,x)\leq d_2(x',x)+d_2(x_k,x')$. Let $k \to \infty $ to see that $x \in S'$. hence $S'$ is closed.

Now let $d_2(x,y) \geq r$. Let $x_k=y+\frac 1 k (y-x)$. Then $d_2(x_k,y)=d_2(0,\frac 1 k (y-x)) \to 0$ as $ k \to \infty$ . Also, $$d_2(x_k,x)=d_2(y+\frac 1 k (y-x),x)$$ $$=d_2((y-x+\frac 1 k (y-x),0)$$ $$ =(1+\frac 1 k) d_2(x,y) >d_2(x,y) \geq r.$$  Hence $y$ is the limit of a sequence from $\{z:d_2(x,z)>r\}.$

Comment: i don't think I get the first part tho, is the sequence's limit x the same x in the question?

Comment: @davidh Sorry, that was  a mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: I see. however shouldn't the first inequality be $r <= d_2(x_k, x)$?

Comment: @davidh Corrected that also. Hope I have fixed all the errors.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how you got the (1+1/k)^n step?

Comment: That was suppose to be just $1+\frac 1 k$.

Comment: I believe this is one last bit lol, but I think for the second part we want x' in the conclusion right? Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: It was not $x'$; it was $y$.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.